# How to enable notifiction "action to choose" after auto-mounting in nautilus

Tags: nautilus

I have Ubuntu with Gnome. The window informing about USB auto-detection (action to choose) always occurs when USB drive was plugged. After removing `~/.config` directory it stopped working.

How to recover this feature? I don't remember, but it supposed to be nautilus notification. USB device is ok and is visible via `lsusb`. Auto-mounting also works.

I don't see an option for this in *gconf-editor* and *nautilus*.

Answer (score 0):

Through Dash: (System Settings) → Details → Removable Media

[image]